# Execution of JS command on load completed of external widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

In this question i use addthis widget as an example, but it's really true for any widget (if generalization is possible)

[addthis](http://addthis.com) is a widget that adds all the social linking to a webpage. However it comes with very limited design customization options. So in order to make it fit to my theme I need to transfer the a tag that are generated by addthis into my own html/css structure.

I tried to use JQuery append method on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var addthis = $("#atftbx");
});
```

However the array that was returned by $("#atftbx") was empty [], which means jquery didn't find the element on the page. I assume that at the point of execution of $(document).ready the widget hasn't been loaded yet. Is there any event that i can listen to and then execute? is there any other way which it can be done?

Not that it matters but just for reference purposes, here is an example of what the widget generates.

```
<div class="addthis_custom_follow">
    <div id="atftbx" class="at-follow-tbx-element addthis-smartlayers animated at4-show">
     <p><span>    </span></p>
     <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_white_style circular">
         <a class="addthis_button_facebook_follow...">
              <span class="at300bs at15nc at15t_facebook">
                   <span class="at_a11y">Follow on Facebook</span>
             </span><span class="addthis_follow_label">Facebook</span>
         </a>
         <a class="......
         </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
function addthisReady(evt) {
    // your jQuery code
}

addthis.addEventListener('addthis.ready', addthisReady);
```

For more info look at http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365497-addthis-javascript-events

EDIT:

For the general purpose I can assume, that you can use event **DOMSubtreeModified** to execute your code, when widget will change HTML of widget's container, like that:

```
var isChanged = false;
$(".widget_container").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    if (! isChanged) {
        isChanged = true;
        // your code
    }
});
```

but it's better to use widget's built-in events, because **DOMSubtreeModified** is buggy in IE 9 (http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php)

Comment: Thanks for the info. The built in widget didn't work for me. I checked in the debugger that indeed it stops, however it couldn't find the dom element.

Comment: but your second suggestion worked. I was able to see the dom element I was looking for. This definitely answers my question but i am curious as for the addthis widget events.